# Identificar checkbox selecionados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

Bom galera eu tenho uma página (view) que faz um select do banco e me retorna as imagens cadastradas para o usuário selecionar um limite de fotos determinado pelo administrador mais queria contar e mostrar para o usuário quantas fotos ele ainda pode selecionar, ou seja, quando ele seleciona uma imagem (um checkbox) ele subtrai 1 do limite e vice-versa, vou deixar o código da view para vocês entenderem melhor

```
        <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="select">
                    <h4 class="info-text"> Selecione suas <b id="contafotos">10</b> fotos: </h4>
                    <div class="row">
                    <?php foreach ($for_fotos as $dados) : ?>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="<?php echo base_url($dados['path'].'/'.$dados['nome']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $dados['nome'] ?>">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <p>
                              <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                  <input class="limited" type="checkbox" value="">
                                  Selecionar
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>  
                    <?php endforeach; ?>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wizard-footer">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-warning btn-wd btn-sm' value='PRÓXIMO' />
                        <!--<input type='button' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-warning btn-wd btn-sm' name='finish' value='Finish' />-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <?php echo anchor('selecao/voltar', 'Voltar', 'class="btn btn-previous btn-fill btn-default btn-wd btn-sm"'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var selec = 10;
      $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
        var total = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').checked;

        if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked')) {
            //$(this).attr("checked")=="checked"
            selec--;
        }
        $("#contafotos").html(selec);
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Esta resposta lhe atende?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#list :checkbox').change(function(){
    $('#list :checkbox').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            /** 
            *Faz o que desejar quando o checkbox estiver marcado
            */
        }
    });
});
```

O que ele faz: sempre que um checkbox que esta dentro da div #list é modificado eu percorro todos os checklists e verifico se esta checado se estiver faço alguma ação.